# How to use map to filter value of field into an iterable of struct

Tags: rust

I would like to filter into an iterable that contain a struct of Person with `map()` instruction but I don't know if it's possible on this way?
I would like to know which is the bast way to complete this task properly in Rust.

```
// This my structure of objet Person
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Person {
    product_id: i64,
    nom: String,
    prenom: String,
    email: Option<String>,
    actif: bool,
}

// Main function which create a person and add this person into a HashMap<i64, Person>
fn main() {
    // create list of person
    let mut personnes = Personnes::new();
    // Create one person
    let person = Person {
        product_id: 1,
        nom: String::from("TestNom"),
        prenom: String::from("TestPrenom"),
        email: Some("test@mail.com".to_string()),
        actif: true,
    };
    // Add person into my iterable
    personnes.add(person);
    // Add few persons...
    // Imagine multiple Person and find person who actif = true
    persons_actives(&personnes);
}

// Something like that :
fn persons_actives(personnes: &Personnes) {
    let persons_actives = personnes
        .inner
        .iter()
        .map(|person.actif| person.actif == true)
        .collect();
}

// But it's maybe impossible in this way ?
```

---

I tried :

```
fn persons_actives(personnes: &Personnes) {
    let persons_actives = personnes.inner.iter().filter(|person| person.actif == true).collect();
}
```

and :

```
fn persons_actives(personnes: &Personnes) {
    let persons_actives = personnes.inner.iter().find(|person| person.actif == true).collect();
}
```

but i have the same error :
"no field actif on type &(&i64, &Person)"

Comment: You are talking about a mysterious `Personnes` struct, but you never show it. How should we solve this if you are hiding the important code?

Comment: Also, welcome to stackoverflow :) Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Further, please provide a [minimal reprodicuble example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and double-check the spelling in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your HashMap values, then `filter()` and `collect()` the result into a Vector.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    is_active: bool
    //other params
}

fn main() {
    // define your map
    let mut map :HashMap<i32,Person> = HashMap::new();

    // init a Person
    let person: Person = Person{
        is_active: true
        // set other params
    };

    // insert it to map
    map.insert(1,person);

    // filter person.is_active == true
    let active_persons : Vec<_> = map.values().filter(|person| person.is_active==true).collect();

    // result
    println!("{:?}",active_persons);
}
```

Now you have your desired result in `active_persons`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response ! Yes, you are right, but i tried find() and also filter() methods but i have the following error : no field `actif` on type `&(&i64, &Person)` Because Person is an Iterable HashMap<i64, Person> so i can't filter or find directly the person which are actives because the filed actif is not acccessible in these way actually, is this right ? Maybe chain map().filter() and so on to catch the field and his value ?

Comment: Please actually test your answers. This doesn't even compile, because `|person.actif|` is not valid Rust syntax.

Comment: @VBO If `inner` is a `HashMap`, then do `.filter(|(_, person)| person.actif)` or `personnes.inner.values().filter(|person| person.actif)`. Note that `==true` is a redundant comparison and can always be ommitted. But again, please provide that information in your question, we can't answer your questions properly if you don't show us how `Personnes` actually looks like. So I now had to infer how it looks like from your error message, which is not how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply,

I have tested this one :

```
let active_persons : Vec<_> = personnes.inner.values().filter(|&person| if_else!(person.actif, true, false)).collect();
```

with ternary-rs library for the if_else syntax.

Your right i shold have noticed the structiure of Personnes which is :

```
struct Personnes {
    inner: HashMap<i64, Person>,
}
```

But i have keep your Vec<_> Structure for the active person.
I created two persons, one is active and the other not and it's worked !

Thanks a lot !